# string type check in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a type check with an element of a pandas dataframe which appears to be a string:

```
type(atmdf.ix[row]['bid'])

<type 'str'>
```

however, if I do a type check I get False:

```
type(atmdf.ix[row]['bid']) is 'str'

False
```

even with the isinstance I get the same unexpected result:

```
isinstance(type(atmdf.ix[row]['bid']), str)

False
```

where am I wrong?

P.S. the content of the dataframe is something like this:

```
atmdf.ix[row]['bid']
'28.5'
```

thank you!

Comment: Your second one is incorrect should be `type(atmdf.ix[row]['bid']) is str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test the string itself with `isintance`, not the type:

```
In [2]: isinstance('string', str)
Out[2]: True
```

So in your case (leaving out the `type(..)`): `isinstance(atmdf.ix[row]['bid'], str)`.

Your first check did not work because you have to compare to `str` (the type) not `'str'` (a string).

Comment: See comment of @EdChum: you have to compare to `str` not `'str'`

Comment: @mspadaccino because you are comparing to a string `'str'` rather than the type `str`

Comment: @mspadaccino : The `type()` function returns a `type` object, not a string.